# What is window.Globalization?? It's cited in jQuery UI Spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What is `window.Globalization`?? It's cited in jQuery UI Spinner.

My Googling skills have failed me.

See https://github.com/Bocoup/jquery-ui/raw/master/ui/jquery.ui.spinner.js

Thanks.

Comment: im not finding it in that source.

Comment: you can see it here: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/spinner/spinner.js?r=4123 , but I don't think it's standard.  It could be just an extension (you can easily create it yourself by doing something like window.prototype.Globalization = *blah*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's the jquery-global plugin. Referenced here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/external/jquery.global.js as a resource. The original is here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-global.

This is just a guess as I'm actually unable to find where the association is made to the window object.